# Criar planilha pelo C# sem ter excel instalado

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, ooxml

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que deve exportar dados para uma planilha de Excel. Preciso saber como montar uma planilha com C#, porém só encontrei tutoriais que exigem o excel instalado no computador.

Gostaria de poder exportar os dados sem depender do excel instalado.

Comment: exporta em aquivo csv, que nada mais é do que texto separado por virgulas, depois fica simples de abrir no excel ou qualquer outro programa

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente, mas esse formato oferece recursos limitados para usos futuros. Queria algo do tipo ods.

Comment: Encontrei outra solução para o problema. Gostaria de poder fixar no tópico, porém o moderador fechou. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @bigown, isso é dúvida comum. Peço que me deixe responder.

Comment: @Alex sua pergunta precisa de mais dois votos para ser reaberta. Caso seja, darei um exemplo em C# de como criar um arquivo *.xlsx com a API do Office.

Comment: @bigown eu tenho um exemplo quase pronto de como fazer isso, é algo bem específico, trivial e super útil.

Comment: Eu reabri, mas é pergunta é uma porcaria, pra falar a verdade estou quase desistindo de tentar manter a ordem do site, essa pergunta claramente é ampola demais, não tem esforço algum e pede tudo pronto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar do [SDK do Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/bb448854.aspx). Deixo a seu critério instalá-lo.

Dito isso, o código pode parecer complexo de início - até você conhecer a estrutura dos arquivos. Vou colocar um passo a passo.

Para se trabalhar com quaisquer arquivos do Office, precisamos dos seguintes namespaces:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
```

E para o Excel, especificamente:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
```

Você começa preparando uma *stream*. A melhor forma de se fazer isso é com uma *stream* de memória, mas você pode utilizar outras formas também dependendo da sua coragem e disposição.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

Agora você cria o objeto que será o arquivo de fato. Repare no uso do comando `using`. Todo o restante do código deve estar dentro do bloco declarado pelo using.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument foo = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    // você vai montar a estrutura do arquivo aqui.
}
```

Um arquivo de excel é feito de "livros" de trabalho (*workbooks*). Cada livro é um elemento XML que conterá planilhas. Vamos inserí-los.

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = foo.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
workbookPart.Workbook.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
```

Lembre-se de onde o código acima deve ser colocado ;)

Agora precisamos montar as planilhas em si. É simples:

```
Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
```

(*sheet* é planilha em inglês)

Cada planilha que você for inserir precisa ter um identificador, único e textual. Esse identificador pode ser arbitrário. Como já usei o termo `foo` para o objeto principal, vou usar `bar` para a chave.

```
string idPlanilha = "bar";
```

E agora adicionamos uma planilha em si. Caso queira acrescentar outras mais, o código é o mesmo. Mude apenas a chave.

```
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>(idPlanilha);
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
Sheet planilha1 = new Sheet()
{
    Id = idPlanilha,
    SheetId = 1, // incremente na próxima
    Name = "minhaPrimeiraPlanilha"
};
sheets.Append(planilha1);
```

Agora já temos uma planilha no objeto que representa o arquivo. Falta só preencher ela. Essa é a parte mais chatinha.

Vamos obter um conjunto de dados de planilha:

```
SheetData dadosPlanilha = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
```

Supondo que você tenha uma `DataTable` chamada `dados`. Você pode passar os dados dela para o conjunto de dados da planilha da seguinte forma:

```
UInt32Value indice = 1;
foreach (DataRow rowDados in dados.Rows)
{
    Row rowExcel = new Row()
    {
        RowIndex = indice
    };

    char letraColuna = 'A';
    foreach (DataColumn column in dados.Columns)
    {
        object valorOriginal = rowDados[column];
        string valorTratado = valorOriginal != null ? valorOriginal.ToString() : ""; // Sanitizaçãozinha básica
        string coordenada = letraColuna.ToString() + indice.ToString();
        Cell celula = new Cell()
        {
            CellReference = coordenada,
            CellValue = new CellValue(valorTratado),
            DataType = CellValues.String
        };

        rowExcel.Append(celula);
        letraColuna = (char)(((int)letraColuna) + 1);
    }
    dadosPlanilha.Append(rowExcel);
    indice++;
}
```

Note que estamos passando todos os valores da `DataTable` para a planilha como strings. Novamente deixo a seu critério como utilizar outros formatos (para datas e números).

Agora, salvamos tudo e fechamos o objeto que representa o arquivo.

```
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
foo.Close();
```

Sabe aquela *stream* que a gente abriu pra representar o arquivo? Ela contém o binário do arquivo agora! Se fosse uma `FileStream`, por exemplo, o arquivo já estaria praticamente escrito agora. Como usamos uma `MemoryStream`, temos o arquivo em memória. Você agora está livre para usá-lo como quiser - recomendo fazer apenas o seguinte, antes de a *stream* para escrever em disco, salvar em um banco de dados ou forçar um download:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

Ah, só mais uma coisa... Como o formato do arquivo vai ser OOXML (no caso, qualquer coisa .xlsx), você precisa do Office pelo menos 2013 para ter compatibilidade completa. Mas deve ser capaz de abrir com o Office a partir do 2007 (caso esteja em alguma repartição pública que ainda tenha essa versão), ou com outras ferramentas como o Google Drive.

Pronto. Por hoje é só, pessoal.

Answer (score 2):

## Use [Spreadsheet Light](http://spreadsheetlight.com)

```
SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();
sl.SetCellValue("A1", "Hello World"); 

sl.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```