# Gerar um arquivo excel no vb.net sem excel instalado

Tags: microsoft-excel, vb.net

Olá,

Tenho uma aplicação que gera planilhas Excel, porém alguns usuários estão tendo diversos problemas (usuários sem licença ou sem o office).
Hoje uso o método COM (usando as dll do office). Gostaria de saber se existe algum outro método.

Comment: Você pode usar [o SDK oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/bb448854.aspx). Com ele você pode criar e editar qualquer arquivo do Office programaticamente, sem precisar ter o Office instalado. Para um exemplo em C#: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221336/1658